# Copy all changelist descriptions while merging in Perforce?

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

I am working with "my" Perforce branch, fixing some small issues in the code. Every now and then I am integrating with another branch ("main").

I write extensive changelist descriptions each time I commit to "my" branch. When I integrate, I would like to have the merging ("my->main") changelist description be a sum of descriptions I wrote for all the changelists in "my" branch since the last merge.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little bit of scripting it should be easy.  You can use `p4 interchanges` to get a list of all pending changelists that will be merged, extract the description from each, and use it as the changelist description when you submit the merge.

Comment: p4 interchanges -l -b BranchMapping / p4 interchanges -l -r -b BranchMapping was what I needed (-l to get the full description). Thx.